# How do I access a local variable in JavaScript, specifically for the setInterval() and clearInterval() methods?

Tags: javascript, scope, setinterval

I am making a Pomodoro Timer in JS.

I am using a 'Start' and a 'Stop' button for it. When the Start button is clicked, the timer starts off at `25:00` min and goes down to `00:00` min.

I have done this with the `Date()` object and the `setInterval()` method. 
What I want is for the user to have a 'Stop' button if they wanna stop the timer before 25 minutes are done.

To do this, I will need to access the variable `x` in which the state of `setInterval()` is stored. This `x` needs to be passed to clearInterval(x). This is how I stop the timer.

Now,
I have 2 separate `startTimer()` and `stopTimer()` functions for the separate `buttons[onclick]`. The state of `setInterval` i.e. variable `x` is in the `startTimer()` function whereas to stop the timer I need to access this local variable inside another function `stopTimer()`

How do I access this local variable?

Here is the relevant code:

```
function startTimer() {

    var toDateTime = new Date().getTime() + 1500000; //adding 25 mins to current time
    console.log("startFunction is on with endDate: " + toDateTime);

    //use setInterval to update every second
    var x = setInterval(function() {
        timerFunc(toDateTime)
    }, 1000); //need to access this var x in stopTimer
} //end startTimer function


function stopTimer() {
    clearInterval(x); //can't access 'x' here, workaround this.
}
```

Comment: You put it outside.

Answer (score 1):

assign `x` without `var` or declare outside function to make scope available to stopTimer function

```
var x;
function startTimer(){

    var toDateTime = new Date().getTime() + 1500000;       //adding 25 mins to current time
    console.log("startFunction is on with endDate: "+toDateTime);
    //use setInterval to update every second
    clearInterval(x); //Clear interval before setInterval to prevent creation of multiple interval 
    x = setInterval(function(){timerFunc(toDateTime)}, 1000); //need to access this var x in stopTimer
}//end startTimer function


function stopTimer(){
    clearInterval(x);    //can't access 'x' here, workaround this.
}
```